# Prevent website from copying my website

Tags: duplicate-content, scraper-sites

I currently have a website that I am maintain and update I am doing my best to get the best seo score as possible so my site gets found on search engines as good as possible. However, recently I found out there is another website that is constantly copying all content from my website.

This website is taking a lot of views away from my website, but I can't find a way to prevent them from copying my data. I was thinking of adding a hotlink prevention to my cdn, but I read this is very bad for SEO, is this true?

Could someone help me to prevent this website from copying my site content or help me to find a way to stop them from doing this?

Comment: Much of what to do depends upon how the site is copying your site. Many times the domain monetizers just create a CNAME record and steal your site, not by copying your site, but by simply pointing to your site. Check the Whois record for the domain and see. If this is the case, use canonical tags and full links to your pages and you will be fine. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not stop this, unless you turn your entire page into an image (and even that's not 100%).

There are a few tricks, but those work with css (place a hidden div over it) or JavaScript (the terrible "no right click allowed"), but they don't use a browser.
They use a (scrapper)bot, which means they get the source, where those solutions aren't applicable.

You should start by adding a cannonical tag to your page, with little luck that'll help a bit. If you dont have it, add a XML sitemap and submit that via Google Webmastertools. It might help Google index your pages first, giving your some of the visitors back.

You could load a paragraph of text, and then use AJAX to load the rest of the articles. That will prevent them from downloading it, but it will also limit your SEO value as bots have a harder time finding the content as well.

If you have the time, you could try to find out the USER AGENT they sent when they visit, researchfor a list user names, and block those via htaccess.
If you can, add region locks. E.g.: I dont have visitors from Russia on my site, I could block IP's from Russia.

Legal action could be an option, but I'm not a lawyer, I don;t know your exact rights here.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I added a cannonical tag, but it looks like they just replace the domain name... Even the links in my sitemap are replaced...

Comment: I have contacted the website owner about this but I have yet to receive a reply. It seemed they were using a reverse proxy to have a live feed of the website on their own domain, I have blocked that domain in my nginx config so their copy is no longer working. Thank you for the help. :)

Comment: @Jerodev I am sure the site owner does not give a rip about you or your site. These are often domain monetizers who think nothing of cheating and stealing.